# gitlab removing shared project to a group

Tags: gitlab

How do we unlink a project, shared (owned) by a user, to a group from which he's been removed ?

before removing the user:

```
group /p1
group /p2
user / p3
```

after the user is removed from the group, "user / p3" still shows up in the groups shared projects. The "Remove Project" action is not available under this projects settings. Is it like I would have been able to "unlink" the project had I not removed the user first ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to go in settings>groups for project P3 and removethe group from there.

Comment: p3 was created by a different user, under his "username" namespace and not the group namespace. I think what you are referring to can be done only by the user since he is the owner of the project. Since I am the group admin, I was able to remove him from the group but it seems this has left a stale project entry under the groups shared projects.

Comment: Well unfortunately I think for now it's the only way. You may submit a bug to gitlab though it looks like a nasty way to spam a group :)

Comment: Yes.. that's what even I was wondering. In this case, although the user was added by me and the original intent was not to spam; the "remove user from group" workflow should have unlinked the project's association from the group. Thanks for your suggestion.. Will try this on the gitlab issue tracker.